ForEach complaining about duplicate values with SwiftData
I have a Category model that's defined like so:
@Model
final class Category {
    @Attribute(.unique) var id: UUID
    var name: String
    var parent_id: UUID //categories can be children of other categories

    init(id: UUID, name: String, parent_id: UUID) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.parent_id = parent_id
    }
}

And I'm getting my categories from an API call and putting it into my View:
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

struct CategoryView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    
    @Query private var categories: [Category]
    @Query(filter: #Predicate<Category>{ $0.parent_id == nil })
        private var top_level_categories: [Category]
    
    var spacing: CGFloat = 25

    var body: some View {
        HStack() {
            Text("Categories")
                .font(.title.bold())
            
            Spacer()
            Text("see all")
        }
        .padding([.bottom, .top], 0)
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                HStack(spacing: spacing) {
                    ForEach(top_level_categories) { category in
                        Text(category.name!)

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear{
            getCategories()
        }
    }
    
    func getCategories()  {
        get_refresh_token { token in
            guard let token = token else {
                return
            }
            var urlRequest = URLRequest (url: URL(string:"https://api.test.com/categories")!)
            urlRequest.httpMethod = "GET"
            urlRequest.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
            urlRequest.addValue("Bearer \(token)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
            
            URLSession.shared
                .dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data, response, error) in
                    do {
                        if let data = data {
                            let c = try JSONDecoder().decode([Category].self, from: data)
                            c.forEach { modelContext.insert($0) }
                            try? modelContext.save()
                        }
                    }
                    catch {
                        print(error)
                    }
                }.resume()
            
        }
    }
    
    
}

This runs fine the first time I run the app but when I run it again, I get the following error:
ForEach<Array<Category>, UUID, Text>: the ID XXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXX occurs multiple times within the collection, this will give undefined results!

Not sure why this is happening since I thought putting the @Attribute(.unique) on ID means that the same category won't get added twice?
Also unsure if I'm representing the parent/child relationship correctly. All I really need to be able to do is filter to 'top level categories' (i.e. no parent_id), and get the sub-categories for a given category.
Thanks!

$0.parent_id == nil, compilation error or typo? parent_id is not declared as optional so you can’t compare to nil.

@JoakimDanielson I rather suspect the typo is that parent_id should be optional, otherwise every category must have a parent, which is impossible.

Apart from the (off-topic) problem I mentioned in my first comment I don’t really see anything wrong with your code so it’s most likely an issue related to the .unique option and/or how you import and save the data from the API call. I think you need to debug that part to see what happens.

Based on this thread, wrapping the modelContext.insert and modelContext.save in DispatchQueue.main.async fixed the issue.

Consider to make getCategories() async

Oh so this is another issue with updating the ModelContext off the main thread/actor
